# (Solved) Zeroth compactly supported cohomology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, examples-counterexamples, homology-cohomology

Let $R$ be a ring and $M$ be a manifold. For every $n$ define $$S_c^n(M;R)=\{\phi\in S^n(M;R)\vert \ \exists K\subseteq M \text{ compact}: \forall \psi:\Delta^n\rightarrow M \text{ with } \operatorname{im}(\psi)\cap K=\emptyset \text{ we have } \phi(\psi)=0\}.$$
Restricting the differential of singular cohomology makes $S_c^{\ast}(M;R)$ a cochain complex. Its cohomology groups are called *compactly supported cohomology groups*.

I read that the zeroth cohomology group with compact support (and coefficients in $R$) is the set of functions $M\rightarrow R$ with compact support that are constant on any continuous path. Is that true? Why is that?

Comment: If you simply follow the definition you will see why this is true.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Is the following correct? $S^0_c(M;R)$, can be identified with the set of functions $M\rightarrow R$ with compact support, where the abelian group structure is given by pointwise addition. Also clearly $B^0_c(M;R)=0$. $S^1_c(M;R)$ can be identified with the set of functions $\phi$ from the set of continuous paths in $M$ into $R$ with the property that there exists a compact set $K_{\phi}\subset M$ such that any path that doesn't pass through $K_\phi$ is sent by $\phi$ to zero. The differential $\delta^0$ sends a function $f:M\rightarrow R$ (with compact support) …

Comment: … to the function $\tilde{f}$ that maps a continuous path $\gamma$ in $M$ to the difference $f(\gamma(1))-f(\gamma(0))$. Thus the zero cocylces $C^0_c(M;R)$ are precisely those functions $M\rightarrow R$ with compact support that agree on any two endpoints of any continuous path in $M$. But the last condition is equivalent to the function being constant on any continuous path in $M$.

Comment: Of course......